# php redirect pages under folder to different domain

Tags: php

Using php, how might I redirect all pages under a folder to a different domain?

Current site:

```
http://www.example.org/dept
http://www.example.org/dept/stuff
http://www.example.org/dept/more
http://www.example.org/dept/more/stuff
```

New site:

```
http://www.example-too.org/pets/stuff
http://www.example-too.org/pets/more
http://www.example-too.org/pets/more/stuff
```

I've learned about how to redirect a single page:

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.example-too.org/pets/more/stuff" );
?>
```

but how to apply this to dozens of pages without creating a php redirect for each one?

**[edit]** I understand using web server config (apache mod_rewrite) and/or .htaccess is the best way to handle multiple redirects like this, but I those options aren't available to me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless one PHP script is used to handle all those URL's already, you need to create a new PHP script for each URL.

You could write some script to automate the process however.

For instance, if it is a Linux server and you are able to run shell scripts, something like this could work (execute in the *htdocs* folder, or equal):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add folders here
FOLDERS=stuff more more/stuff    

for folder in $FOLDERS; do
    {
        echo '<?php'
        echo 'header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");'
        echo "header(\"Location: http://www.example-too.org/pets/$folder\");"
    } > dept/$folder/index.php
done
```

If you are unable to run shell scripts, you could translate the script into PHP.

Comment: Whilst a perfectly valid solution, I'd hate to be the one who comes in to maintain it ;)

Comment: Hopefully it won't need maintaining. It just needs to go up long enough for the search engines to register the change. After 6 months or so the whole ./dept section will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that the better way to do this through "Redirect" command in the web server config or .htaccess

Comment: Absolutally. You can use a regex to match anything matching `www.example.org` and do a 301 to `www.example-too.org`

Comment: granted, except that I don't have access to web server config and htaccess is disabled. I added a note to the main post that using those methods is preffered if avilable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mikael, I modified your script a bit to deal with my html pages instead of folders:

```
#!/bin/env bash

DEST=http://www.example-too.org/pets
FILES=`find . |grep \.html$ -`

for xfile in $FILES; do
    file=${xfile:2}         # strip leading ./
    file=${file%%.html}.php # change extension from .html to .php
                            # comment out preceeding line to overwrite source .html
    {
        echo '<?php'
        echo 'header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");'
        echo "header(\"Location: $DEST/$file\");"
        echo '?>'
    } > $file
    echo created $file
done
```

Comment: You forgot the question mark in the closing PHP tag (which, by the way is optional unless you want to stick some plain HTML/text after the PHP code).